# Counting depending on a field

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with container numbers and a completed_on date field with a timestamp. It also have the vessel id, and crane id. I need to count the amount of completed containers and not completed, by asking if the completed_on is null or not.

I've written something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
select vessel,
  crane_no,
  count(container_no) tot_moves,
  case when completed_on is null then count(container_no) end as pending,
  case when completed_on is not null then count(container_no) end as completed,
min(completed_on) first_m,
max(completed_on) last_m
from
containers
group by vessel, crane_no, completed_on
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the count() around the cases.

```
select vessel,
  crane_no,
  count(container_no) tot_moves,
  count(case when completed_on is null then container_no end) as pending,
  count(case when completed_on is not null then container_no end) as completed,
min(completed_on) first_m,
max(completed_on) last_m
from
containers
group by vessel, crane_no;
```

Answer (score 2):

You were pretty close... the `case` statement should be inside of your aggregate `count` function:

```
select 
  vessel,
  crane_no,
  count(container_no) tot_moves,
  count(case when completed_on is null then 1 end) as pending,
  count(case when completed_on is not null then 1 end) as completed,
  min(completed_on) first_m,
  max(completed_on) last_m
from
  containers
group by 
  vessel, 
  crane_no, 
  completed_on
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    select 
      vessel,
      crane_no,
      count(container_no) tot_moves,
      count(case when completed_on is null then 1 end) as pending,
      count(case when completed_on is not null then 1 end) as completed,
      min(completed_on) first_m,
      max(completed_on) last_m
    from containers group by  vessel, crane_no, completed_on
```

Answer (score 2):

There's another way to do this, not using `CASE`.  I'm not sure how Oracle optimizes things, but this *may* be faster (you'll need to do your own profiling).

```
select vessel,
       crane_no,
       count(container_no) tot_moves,
       count(*) - count(completed_on) as pending,
       count(completed_on) as completed,
       min(completed_on) first_m,
       max(completed_on) last_m
from containers
group by vessel, crane_no, completed_on
```

This works because pretty much all aggregates (including `COUNT()`) will ignore nulls.  You can use the difference between the total rows and the count of the completed rows to get the pending moves.  Also, `count(completed_on)` *should* be cached, and won't be run twice (some RDBMSs allow re-use of column aliases in the `SELECT` clause, but I don't know if Oracle supports this).

Comment: The count(1) ought to be count(*), but that aside, +1

Comment: @DavidAldridge - why? From a performance standpoint, a semantic standpoint, or a readability standpoint?  Is there some consideration I should be aware of?  (I was initially going to say something about only listing those columns actually needed, but the optimizer is probably smart enough to remove that cost).

Comment: Potentially from all of those standpoint. count(\*) is the standard, documented syntax, and anything else is either worse or no improvement, and smacks in an undefendable way of some kind of clever trick that hints at an improvement on count(\*). There have been myths that count(\*) requires Oracle to read "the entire row", which is plainly nonsense, but avoiding count\(*) runs the risk of perpetuating an untruth.

Comment: Okay, I can buy the standards bit.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
select vessel,
    crane_no,
    count(container_no) tot_moves,
    sum(case when completed_on is null then 1 else 0 end) as pending,
    sum(case when completed_on is not null then 1 else 0 end) as completed,
    min(completed_on) first_m,
    max(completed_on) last_m
from containers
group by vessel, crane_no, completed_on;
```

The `case` is deciding whether each row should be counted, and the `sum` works out the actual count based on those.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Very fast response. Appreciated it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  vessel,
  crane_no,
  COUNT(container_no)                                       AS "tot_moves",
  SUM(CASE WHEN completed_on IS NULL     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "pending",
  SUM(CASE WHEN completed_on IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "completed",
  MIN(completed_on) first_m,
  MAX(completed_on) last_m
FROM containers
GROUP BY vessel, crane_no;
```

Answer (score 0):

the count function doesnt counts null by default.
you can manipulate the query by using nvl2 function to help you count only nulls.
example :

```
select count(completed_on) as completed , 
       count(nvl2(completed_on,null,1)) as pending
from containers;
```